# Reverse Diff function in R

Tags: r, diff

Is there a function that will reverse the diff function? Essentially if I had the vector

```
a = c(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Instead of

```
diff(a)
[1] 1 1 1
```

I would like a function that does something like

```
altdiff(a)
[1] -1 -1 -1
```

I know that I could simply reverse the vector and apply diff, or write my own function, but I was wondering if there was an existing function that can do this.

Comment: why not `diff(a) *  -1`

Comment: or `diff(rev(a))`

Comment: diff(a) * -1 is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks, and wow I feel a little stupid

Comment: Or, just for fun, `a - lead(a)`

Comment: In fact, I just ran timings on a vector of length 1 million with `microbenchmark` and was surprised to find that the `lead` method runs in about 2/3 the time of the `diff` method.

Comment: @d.b you know, you're right. I'd forgotten. It is `dplyr`! So, to use `lead`, you'll need to run `library(dplyr)` first.

Comment: @eipi10 the `lead` solution actually works better for me here (although I did just have to install `dplyr`) as it produces an `NA`. The vector I am trying to diff is going to be compared to another vector that should be the differences, so It saves me an extra step of tacking on an `NA`.

Comment: However it might be useful to note that `a - lead(a)` doesn't produce the same output as `diff(a) * -1` or `diff(rev(a))` would