# Reconstruct seasonally (and non seasonally) differenced data in R

Tags: r, difference

I've achieved stationary data for use in arima ([see](https://www.real-statistics.com/time-series-analysis/time-series-miscellaneous/arimax-model-and-forecast/)) forecasts using seasonal and non seasonal differencing.  Now how do I revert back to the original date using the differenced data?

```
raw <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thistleknot/Python-Stock/master/data/combined_set.csv",row.names=1,header=TRUE)

temp <- raw$CSUSHPINSA

#tells me to seasonally difference 1 time
print(nsdiffs(ts(temp,frequency=4)))

temp_1 <- temp-dplyr::lag(temp,1*season)

#tells me I need to difference it once more
print(ndiffs(temp_2))

temp_2 <- temp_1-dplyr::lag(temp_1,1)

#shows data is somewhat stationary
plot(temp_2)

#gives me back the original dataset if I only had seasonal differencing
na.omit(dplyr::lag(raw$CSUSHPINSA ,4)+temp_1)

#how to do this with temp_2?
```

Some references
[Pandas reverse of diff()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49903037/pandas-reverse-of-diff)
[Reverse Diff function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47683923/reverse-diff-function-in-r)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I got it

```
dplyr::lag(raw$CSUSHPINSA ,4) + dplyr::lag(temp_1,1)+temp_2
```

More complete examples

```
temp <- raw$MSPUS

#print(nsdiffs(ts(temp,frequency=4)))

#temp_1 <- temp-dplyr::lag(temp,1*season)

print(ndiffs(temp_1))

temp_1 <- temp-dplyr::lag(temp,1)
temp_2 <- temp_1-dplyr::lag(temp_1,1)

#forecast values of temp_2
temp_3 <- dplyr::lag(temp_1,1)+temp_2

temp_4 = (dplyr::lag(raw$MSPUS ,1) + temp_3)

new_temp_2_values = c(8000,10000)

extended <- c(temp_4,tail(c(c(temp_3),tail(temp_4,1)+cumsum(tail(temp_3,1)+cumsum(new_temp_2_values))),length(new_temp_2_values)))

print(extended)
```

Wrote a more involved version here
https://gist.github.com/thistleknot/eeaf1631f736e20806c37107f344d50e